# Como saber si un elemento esta solapando a otro? en python con tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Mi programa hay unos cubos que contienen una función que hace que se puedan arrastrar, lo que tengo que hace es que cuando el Rectángulo rojo (en el código se llama "cubo1") este por arriba de la zona gris (en el código se llama "ZonaTrbj") pase algo y cuando no este pase otra cosa, como por ejemplo aparezca un mensaje en pantalla que diga "Hola!!!" y cuando no este desaparezca.

Mi problema es que no se como hacer para que el programa identifique si cubo1 esta por encima del ZonaTrbj, probé con el "canvas.coords" pero además que no funcionaba, se veían mal los rectángulos con el canvas en vez de en label.otra cosa que probe fue con:

```
Ejemplo=Label.place_info(cubo1)
```

pero tampoco me dio resultado, Dejo el código por si hay un error que yo no encontré:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

#funcion temporal
def donothing():
   x = 0

#Creacion de ventana
window = Tk()
window.title  ('SLP: Simply Learn Programming')
window.geometry('1550x1250')

#barra de opciones superior
menubar = Menu(window)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="Help Index", command=donothing)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=donothing)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

#funciones para arrastrar bloques
def drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y
    

    

def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)
    cubo1 = Label(window,bg="red",width=15,height=3)
    cubo1.place(x=15,y=50)


    
       

#los bloques
ZonaTrbj = Canvas(window,bg="grey",width=700,height=1000)
ZonaTrbj.place(x=270,y=0)
    
cubo1 = Label(window,bg="red",width=15,height=3)
cubo1.place(x=15,y=50)

cubo2 = Label(window,bg="blue",width=15,height=3)
cubo2.place(x=140,y=50)


cubo3 = Label(window,bg="green",width=15,height=3)
cubo3.place(x=15,y=115)

cubo4 = Label(window,bg="violet",width=15,height=3)
cubo4.place(x=140,y=115)

cubo1.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
cubo1.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)

cubo2.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
cubo2.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)

cubo3.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
cubo3.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)

cubo4.bind("<Button-1>",drag_start)
cubo4.bind("<B1-Motion>",drag_motion)

#cubo1 menu de click derecho


def Ayuda():
    ventana_ayuda = tk.Toplevel()
    ventana_ayuda.title("Ventana de ayuda")
    ventana_ayuda.config(width=700, height=500)
    boton_cerrar = ttk.Button(
        ventana_ayuda,
        text="Cerrar ventana", 
        command=ventana_ayuda.destroy
    )

def Configuraciones():
     ventana_congif = tk.Toplevel()
     ventana_congif.title("Ventana de configuracion")
     ventana_congif.config(width=300, height=200)
     boton_cerrar = ttk.Button(
          ventana_congif,
          text="Cerrar ventana", 
          command=ventana_congif.destroy
    )

def my_popup(e):
    my_menu.tk_popup(e.x_root, e.y_root)

# Create a Menu
my_menu = Menu(cubo1, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_command(label="Ayuda", command=Ayuda)
my_menu.add_command(label="Configuraciones", command=Configuraciones)
my_menu.add_separator()
my_menu.add_command(label="Salir", command=cubo1.quit)

cubo1.bind("<Button-3>", my_popup)

#cubo2 menu de click derecho





def my_popup(e):
    my_menu.tk_popup(e.x_root, e.y_root)

# Create a Menu
my_menu = Menu(cubo2, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_command(label="Ayuda", command=Ayuda)
my_menu.add_command(label="Configuraciones", command=Configuraciones)
my_menu.add_separator()
my_menu.add_command(label="Salir", command=cubo2.quit)

cubo2.bind("<Button-3>", my_popup)

#cubo3 menu de click derecho






# Create a Menu
my_menu3 = Menu(cubo3, tearoff=False)
my_menu3.add_command(label="Ayuda", command=Ayuda)
my_menu3.add_command(label="Configuraciones", command=Configuraciones)
my_menu3.add_separator()
my_menu3.add_command(label="Salir", command=cubo3.quit)

cubo3.bind("<Button-3>", my_popup)

#cubo4 menu de click derecho







# Create a Menu
my_menu = Menu(cubo4, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_command(label="Ayuda", command=Ayuda)
my_menu.add_command(label="Configuraciones", command=Configuraciones)
my_menu.add_separator()
my_menu.add_command(label="Salir", command=cubo4.quit)

cubo4.bind("<Button-3>", my_popup)


window.config(menu=menubar)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: La función [`find_overlapping`](https://tkinter-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/canvas.html#Canvas.find_overlapping) puede servirte.

Comment: Los métodos del canvas no te van a funcionar, ya que los labels que estás usando NO forman parte de dicho. No se cual es el objetivo del programa, pero te recomiendo, dentro de lo posible, crear items en el Canvas (por ejemplo, para rectangulos, usa create_rectangle) y guarda sus respectivos ids para luego manipularlos. Si no te queda de otra que crear un widget, usa create_window (ten en cuenta que esto crea un "agujero" o  "ventana" en el canvas para poder mostrar el widget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que es solo mostrar un mensaje al poner los cuadrados sobre la zona de trabajo podrías como algo simple, implementar un label:

```
#los bloques
ZonaTrbj = Canvas(window,bg="grey",width=700,height=1000)
ZonaTrbj.place(x=270,y=0)

mensaje = Label(window, text=' ')
mensaje.place(x=15, y=190)

cubo1 = Label(window,bg="red",width=15,height=3)
cubo1.place(x=15,y=50)
```

como ves lo único que hice fue agregar un label
y para el mensaje detectar en que coordenada está el widget

```
def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x=x,y=y)
    
    cubo1 = Label(window,bg="red",width=15,height=3)
    cubo1.place(x=15,y=50)
    
    if x >= 255:
        mensaje.config(text='Hola')
    if x <= 254:
        mensaje.config(text='')
```

donde solo agregue un condicional

eso es básicamente una posible solución.